# Symfony and Doctrine - ParameterBag could not be converted to string

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I got this error:

> Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class
>   Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag could not be converted
>   to string

I use Symfony 3 and Doctrine Query Builder

```
$qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
        $qb->select('c')
                ->from('AppBundle:Certificate', 'c')
                ->where(' c.enabled = 1')
                ->where(' c.title LIKE :search')
                ->orderBy('c.title', $order)
                ->setParameter('search', '%' . $search . '%' );

        $query = $qb->getQuery();

        return $query->getResult();
```

I try add _toString to my Entity like this:

```
public function __toString() {
        return $this->title;
    }
```

but I have not changed it, I will need to use c columns for the same search with LIKE **where(cc1 LIKE: search OR cc2 LIKE: search)**

Is there any solution? I need to search with LIKE two columns in which the given search string and I must use %:search%

Thank you

Comment: We need more context. What are the values of the `$order` and `$search` variables?

Comment: You get this error because you are trying to use a ParameterBag object in a string context. It has nothing to do with your entities.

Comment: i think you are looking in the wrong place: check the error where you use the request or the session (the place where the object parameterBag is usually used)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ParameterBag object must be for your $order or $search parameters retrieve by the request object. Try to dump it before the query in order to see what there is inside.

Comment: Ok now I understand, I was accustomed to working differently with a form from another framework, sorry for that. 
`ParameterBag {#69 ▼
  #parameters: array:1 [▼
    "form" => array:2 [▼
      "searchbar" => "kopa"
      "_token" => "sc4ad4vwq2sigMUDtCoyrLYas5hseanPFtg-8sC-HDg"
    ]
  ]
}`

Comment: If this dump is for your `$search` variable, you should extract only the `searchBar` value

Comment: I handle my form in handle method i my controler with Request param, is there any recomendations how can I work with requesty object from form ? it is necessary to treat the data against SQL Injection, and the something like that?

Comment: The `setParameter` method is a [safe method](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/security.html#user-input-and-doctrine-orm) used to avoid SQL Injection.